# Find Duplicates in Dataframe and Return First Index values compared with Duplicate Index values

Tags: python, indexing, duplicates

I am hoping you can help.

I have a dataframe with duplicate string values but different Index aka ID values.
I am trying to find the index/IDs values where the strings are duplicates with the twist to compare the first index/ID values with the duplicate row index/IDs.

Here is a sample for the input data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'], 
        [7, 'verything is in a state of change. There ...'], 
        [52, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'],
        [84, 'verything is in a state of change. There ...'],
        [5699, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'],
        [105687, 'you have managed to get ahead'],
        [654684684, 'More Strings']
        ]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Index_ID', 'Strings'])
df.set_index('Index_ID', inplace= True)
df
```

[image]

Here is a sample for the format of the ideal output data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 52], 
        [1, 5699],
        [7, 84]        
       ]
  
duplicate_indexes = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['First_Index_ID', 'Duplicate_Index_ID'])
duplicate_indexes
```

[image]

The dataframe I am working with is large with long strings, this an effort to reduce the size but retaining the Indexes/IDs

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
res = (
    df
    .groupby('Strings').agg(
        First_Index_ID=('Index_ID', 'first'),
        Duplicate_Index_ID=('Index_ID', lambda c: c.to_list()[1:])
    )
    .explode('Duplicate_Index_ID')
    .loc[lambda df: df['Duplicate_Index_ID'].notna()]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

- Grouping over column `Strings` collects the rows that have the same string.
- Then aggregate the groups into 2 new columns, the ones you want: The first one picks the first `Index_ID` of the group, and the second one puts all other indices, the duplicates, in a list.
- Now `.explode` the column with the duplicates list, and remove those rows in the result that are without duplicates (`.explode` turns empty lists into a `NaN`).

Result for your example is:

```
   First_Index_ID Duplicate_Index_ID
0               1                 52
1               1               5699
2               7                 84
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you.
Did not know, python had an explode function. (cool naming)

Really appreciate it, I tried doing it with joins and simulating a sql dense_rank function in python but never really got the results that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> can u check this code it should help

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'],
        [7, 'verything is in a state of change. There ...'],
        [52, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'],
        [84, 'verything is in a state of change. There ...'],
        [5699, 'online delivery, and now offer dedicated learning platforms...'],
        [105687, 'you have managed to get ahead'],
        [654684684, 'More Strings']
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Index_ID', 'Strings'])
df1 = df.groupby('Strings')['Index_ID'].apply(list).reset_index(name='duplicates')
print(df1['duplicates'])
```

Comment: Thank you Wael for the reply, umm still a little new to python, how would I put the output into a dataframe to match the above sample. I could then export the output into MS SQL server to remove the duplicates and keep the IDs on file